# JDBC connection slow when SQL Server installed on remote server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

we are developing a web application that use SQL Server 2016 (Express) as a database engine.

We have noticed that the queries we make from application side take  20-30ms (average) when SQL Server is installed locally while, if installed on a remote machine, it take 400-500ms. We tried different versions of JDBC (now version 7.2.2) but the timing is the same. Both PC are connected on same switch.

The connection string we use is:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://${database.address};SelectMethod=cursor;database=${database.name};useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;charactetrResultSets=UTF-8
```

We tried to delete `SelectMethod=cursor;` and the timing improve but not significantly.

It is not a DNS problem because as address we use the IP.
Can someone tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Your question title says "connection is slow", however in the body you claim that the _queries_ are slow. Which one is it? Establishing the connection, or running the queries?

Comment: How much data is being transferred? If it's a lot of data, then network (Wifi...?) latency can very well be a significant factor. Have you tried running the same workload to that server from SQL Management Studio or similar, and how long did that take?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ...sorry ...queries are slow.

Comment: @PeterB ...the data are not so much and we are not connected on wifi but with cable. On SQL Management Studio the same queries are very fast.

Comment: Just a side note: Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017) to see what connection properties you should actually be using. For examle, `useUnicode=true` is for MySQL JDBC, not SQL Server JDBC. The irrelevant properties may not be slowing you down, but they do make things more confusing.

Comment: Also re: "On SQL Management Studio the same queries are very fast." - Judging the execution *and retrieval* time by running queries in SSMS can be misleading because SSMS will return the first few rows immediately and then continue to fetch the remaining rows in the background. I just tested retrieving 1_000_000 rows from a remote server and the first ~20 rows appeared in the query grid almost immediately while it took another 90 seconds to retrieve the remaining ~999_980 rows.

Comment: @GordThompson ...i tryed with jdbc:sqlserver://${database.address};databaseName=${database.name} but nothing is changed. As already mentioned, the data are not so much, about 200-300 rows. Thanks